# How this output is coming out of C++ comparator and how bool operator > () const is working

Tags: c++, stl, comparator

Can anyone please explain the output of this program? I am not able to understand how bool operator > () const is producing this output!

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class Person
{
public:
    float age;
    string name;

    bool operator>(const Person &rhs) const
    {
        cout << age << " " << rhs.age << endl;
        return age > rhs.age;
    }
};

int main()
{
    multiset<Person, greater<>> multiset = {
        {25, "Rupesh"},
        {30, "Hitesh"},
        {20, "Ram"}};
    return 0;
}
```

The output is this:

```
30 25
30 25
30 25
20 25
20 25
```

Comment: `std::multiset` also has to test for equality this can be synthesised from 2 calls to  `operator>` example: `!(a > b || b > a)`

Comment: The exact calls made to the comparison operator depend on the implementation of `multiset`.